# Non-toric affine variety containing a torus

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties

Part of the definition of an affine toric variety is that the action of the torus sitting as an open dense subset of the variety extends algebraically to the whole variety.  Is there an easy example of a variety which contains an open subset isomorphic to a torus for which the action cannot be extended algebraically?

Comment: Blow up two or more distinct points on a line in $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Comment: MP: I think he wants an affine example.

Comment: Ok, then glue together two distinct points in $\mathbb{A}^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by glue together points?  Will this still be separated and irreducible?

Comment: You just need to define the local ring at the glued spot.  If you choose to specify that the intersection is transverse, then you will get a separated irreducible scheme.